# ParseUser error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

[image]I'm using Parse in my project. I need to get some ParseUser data and show it.
But when I try to get `Phone1` `Phone2` and `Gender` and cast it to a string using `user.get("Phone1").toString()` I get a nullPointerException, but I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
public class Profile extends Activity
{

RelativeLayout menu;
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
TextView name;
TextView age;
TextView gender;
ImageView photo;
EditText address;
EditText email;
EditText phone1;
EditText phone2;
TextView counter;
ProgressBar loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    menu = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuProfile);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textProfileName);
    age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textProfileBirth);
    gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textProfileGender);
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldProfileAddress);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldProfileEmail);
    phone1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldProfilePhone1);
    phone2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldProfilePhone2);
    counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textProfileCounter);
    loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProfile);
    name.setText(user.get("Name").toString());
    age.setText(user.get("BirthDay").toString() + "/" + user.get("BirthMonth").toString() + "/" + user.get("BirthYear").toString());
    gender.setText(user.get("Gender").toString());//I got the error here
    email.setText(user.getEmail());
    phone1.setText(user.get("Phone1").toString());//I get the error here
    phone2.setText(user.get("Phone2").toString());//I got the error here        
    counter.setText(Integer.parseInt(user.get("Trocas").toString()));        
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(user.get("Lat").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(user.get("Lng").toString());
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        address.setText(geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1).get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "\n" + geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1).get(0).getLocality() + "," + geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1).get(0).getAdminArea());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ParseFile file = (ParseFile)user.get("Photo");
        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    photo.setImageBitmap(img1);
                } else {
                    Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                }
            }
        });        
}
```

`Phone1`, `Phone2` and `Gender` are Strings and they have a value on my Parse table.

So, what should I do to get this working, I can't just put a `if(user.get("Gender)!=null)`, I must have this information.

Actualization:

I've tryed `phone1.setText(String.valueOf(user.get("Phone1")));` and it shows null. I'm 100% sure that there is data in my table. It's not null.

Comment: Could you include code showing how you set the Gender, Phone1, and Phone2 values?  These probably aren't being set to the ParseUser object.

Comment: They are setted. I thought that this could be the problem, so I chaged manually the values in my Parse table. So the values are setted in one way or another.

Comment: If you are getting a string value from the user.get call, then that leaves the TextView being null.  Are you sure those are created in your xml layout?

Comment: Yes, I put "Error" inside the `phone1.settext()` and it shows Error in my activity.

Comment: can you take a printscreen of your table in parse please and add it to your question?

Comment: I have other columns, but they doesn't matter for this.